# How to handle interrupts from a PCI device that already have a non shareable handler in a Linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, qemu, pci

I'm learning Linux kernel PCI development with QEMU using the [educational edu PCI device](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/v2.7.0/hw/misc/edu.c).

If I use the device with:

```
-device edu
```

it is inserted since boot, and my interrupts get number 11 and work well.

However, I started playing with inserting the device after boot with the monitor command:

```
device_add edu
```

followed by:

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

If I do that, the IRQ is getting assigned to an interrupt 0, which already has a non-shareable interrupt on it (timer), and my:

```
 request_irq(pci_irq, irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED, "pci_irq_handler0", &major)
```

fails with message:

```
 genirq: Flags mismatch irq 0. 00000080 (pci_irq_handler0) vs. 00015a00 (timer)
```

From the kernel source, we see that `0x80` is the shareable flag, which is not present in the timer.

Is this a bug in the edu device, or is there something I can do about it in my kernel module?

The state with `-device` on boot can :

```
device      BDF      IRQ
==========  =======  ===
edu         00:04.0  10
virtio-pci  00:05.0  11
```

while `device_add` gives:

```
device      BDF      IRQ
==========  =======  ===
virtio-pci  00:04.0  10
edu         00:05.0   0
```

so we see that `edu` and `virtio-pci` swapped places on the probe, but not IRQs unfortunately.

The [full device code with all boilerplate is on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/fa9c635a2e7877ef17974cf36bbe350225d62b52/kernel_module/pci.c), and here is a minimized reproduction version:

```
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>

#define BAR 0
#define CDEV_NAME "lkmc_pci"
#define EDU_DEVICE_ID 0x11e8
#define IO_IRQ_ACK 0x64
#define IO_IRQ_STATUS 0x24
#define QEMU_VENDOR_ID 0x1234

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static struct pci_device_id pci_ids[] = {
    { PCI_DEVICE(QEMU_VENDOR_ID, EDU_DEVICE_ID), },
    { 0, }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(pci, pci_ids);

static int major;
static int pci_irq;
static struct pci_dev *pdev;
static void __iomem *mmio;

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner   = THIS_MODULE,
};

static irqreturn_t irq_handler(int irq, void *dev)
{
    int devi;
    irqreturn_t ret;
    u32 irq_status;

    devi = *(int *)dev;
    irq_status = ioread32(mmio + IO_IRQ_STATUS);
    pr_info("irq_handler irq = %d dev = %d irq_status = %llx\n",
            irq, devi, (unsigned long long)irq_status);
    iowrite32(irq_status, mmio + IO_IRQ_ACK);
    ret = IRQ_HANDLED;
    return ret;
}

static int pci_probe(struct pci_dev *dev, const struct pci_device_id *id)
{
    u8 val;

    pr_info("pci_probe\n");
    major = register_chrdev(0, CDEV_NAME, &fops);
    pdev = dev;
    if (pci_enable_device(dev) < 0) {
        dev_err(&(pdev->dev), "pci_enable_device\n");
        goto error;
    }
    if (pci_request_region(dev, BAR, "myregion0")) {
        dev_err(&(pdev->dev), "pci_request_region\n");
        goto error;
    }
    mmio = pci_iomap(pdev, BAR, pci_resource_len(pdev, BAR));
    pci_read_config_byte(dev, PCI_INTERRUPT_LINE, &val);
    pci_irq = val;
    if (request_irq(pci_irq, irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED, "pci_irq_handler0", &major) < 0) {
        dev_err(&(dev->dev), "request_irq\n");
        goto error;
    }
    /* This makes the device generate an interrupt. */
    iowrite32(0x12345678, mmio + 0x60);
    return 0;
error:
    return 1;
}

static void pci_remove(struct pci_dev *dev)
{
    pr_info("pci_remove\n");
    free_irq(pci_irq, &major);
    pci_release_region(dev, BAR);
    unregister_chrdev(major, CDEV_NAME);
}

static struct pci_driver pci_driver = {
    .name     = "lkmc_pci",
    .id_table = pci_ids,
    .probe    = pci_probe,
    .remove   = pci_remove,
};

static int myinit(void)
{
    if (pci_register_driver(&pci_driver) < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void myexit(void)
{
    pci_unregister_driver(&pci_driver);
}

module_init(myinit);
module_exit(myexit);
```

Possibly related: https://serverfault.com/questions/70585/manually-assign-a-pci-card-to-an-interrupt

Comment: The value in `PCI_INTERRUPT_LINE` register is written by software, not the device itself. It doesn't actually determine what interrupt the device uses. That's determined by the physical PCI interrupt pin it uses and how that pin gets routed through the motherboard to the interrupt controller. A value of the zero suggests that software, either the BIOS or the Linux kernel, hasn't determined or wasn't able to determine what interrupt that card uses and write the correct value to the register.

Comment: You have to use proper interface to get an IRQ line. By default it's presented in `struct pci_dev` as `irq`.

Comment: @0andriy isn't that what `pci_read_config_byte(dev, PCI_INTERRUPT_LINE, &val);` is doing?

Comment: Not exactly. Check `pci_read_irq()`. Though in your case it will not help since the issue you presumable have with PCI BIOS (see first comment).

Comment: @0andriy you are right, `dev->irq` contained the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by 0andriy, we need to use `dev->pci` instead of reading the config with `pci_read_config_byte(dev, PCI_INTERRUPT_LINE, &val);`
. TODO follow kernel code and understand exactly why. This works:

```
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>

#define BAR 0
#define CDEV_NAME "lkmc_hw_pci_min"
#define EDU_DEVICE_ID 0x11e9
#define QEMU_VENDOR_ID 0x1234

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static struct pci_device_id id_table[] = {
    { PCI_DEVICE(QEMU_VENDOR_ID, EDU_DEVICE_ID), },
    { 0, }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(pci, id_table);
static int major;
static struct pci_dev *pdev;
static void __iomem *mmio;
static struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner   = THIS_MODULE,
};

static irqreturn_t irq_handler(int irq, void *dev)
{
    pr_info("irq_handler irq = %d dev = %d\n", irq, *(int *)dev);
    iowrite32(0, mmio + 4);
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static int probe(struct pci_dev *dev, const struct pci_device_id *id)
{
    pr_info("probe\n");
    major = register_chrdev(0, CDEV_NAME, &fops);
    pdev = dev;
    if (pci_enable_device(dev) < 0) {
        dev_err(&(pdev->dev), "pci_enable_device\n");
        goto error;
    }
    if (pci_request_region(dev, BAR, "myregion0")) {
        dev_err(&(pdev->dev), "pci_request_region\n");
        goto error;
    }
    mmio = pci_iomap(pdev, BAR, pci_resource_len(pdev, BAR));
    pr_info("dev->irq = %u\n", dev->irq);
    if (request_irq(dev->irq, irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED, "pci_irq_handler0", &major) < 0) {
        dev_err(&(dev->dev), "request_irq\n");
        goto error;
    }
    iowrite32(0x12345678, mmio);
    return 0;
error:
    return 1;
}

static void remove(struct pci_dev *dev)
{
    pr_info("remove\n");
    free_irq(dev->irq, &major);
    pci_release_region(dev, BAR);
    unregister_chrdev(major, CDEV_NAME);
}

static struct pci_driver pci_driver = {
    .name     = CDEV_NAME,
    .id_table = id_table,
    .probe    = probe,
    .remove   = remove,
};

static int myinit(void)
{
    if (pci_register_driver(&pci_driver) < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void myexit(void)
{
    pci_unregister_driver(&pci_driver);
}

module_init(myinit);
module_exit(myexit);
```